# Pivotgrid prefilter settings

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, devexpress

i want to change devexpress pivotgrid prefilter with code. I am using linqtosql method for bind data in c# MVC.

**PivotGridPartialview.cshtml**

```
settings.Fields.Add(field =>
    {
        field.Area = PivotArea.RowArea;
        field.FieldName = "DefTarih";
        field.Caption = "Tarih";
        field.SortOrder = PivotSortOrder.Descending;
        field.ValueFormat.FormatType = DevExpress.Utils.FormatType.DateTime;
        field.ValueFormat.FormatString = "dd/MM/yyyy";
        field.AreaIndex = 0;        
    });
var Tarih1 = System.DateTime.Parse("01." + System.DateTime.Today.Month.ToString() + "." + System.DateTime.Today.Year.ToString());
var Tarih2 = System.DateTime.Parse(System.DateTime.DaysInMonth(System.DateTime.Today.Year, System.DateTime.Today.Month).ToString() +
        "." + System.DateTime.Today.Month.ToString() + "." + System.DateTime.Today.Year.ToString());
settings.Prefilter.CriteriaString = "[DefTarih] between ('" + Tarih1 + "','" + Tarih2 + "')";
```

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult PivotGridPartial()
{
    var model = db.USDRapors;
    return PartialView("_PivotGridPartial", model);
}
```

When pivotgrid loaded with this code i see prefilter bottom of pivotgrid correctly. But datas not effected with prefilter. When changed start date in prefilter, prefilter works otherwise not works.
Which method can use for changing prefilter in code and work at opening page?

Comment: I think you need to use the ASPxPivotGrid.PrefilterCriteriaChanged or ASPxPivotGrid.GridLayout events

Comment: I changed tarih1 variable wrapping # character and it's not showing data. Somehow filtercriteria is not correct in my code. I don't understand.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is between operator. If i change the code below this message, its working.

```
settings.Prefilter.CriteriaString = "[DefTarih] ='" + Tarih1 + "'"
```

It's strange tried other operators and all of other operators not working. Also below this code not working.

```
settings.Prefilter.CriteriaString = "DefTarih => '" + Tarih1 + "' And [DefTarih] =<'" 
+ Tarih2 + "'"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this if data is numeric:

```
settings.Prefilter.CriteriaString = "DefTarih => " + Tarih1 + " And [DefTarih] =< " + Tarih2
```

you are using "between" and "=<" which are comparing operators, and these not able to compare or find value between two Strings value.

Comment: An error this time like DevExpress.Data.Filtering.Exceptions.CriteriaParserException: 'Parser error at line 0, character 12: syntax error; ("[DefTarih] ={FAILED HERE}> 1.12.2019 00:00:00 And [DefTarih] =< 31.12.2019 00:00:00")'